# Adjust SQL to cater for bad date entered into database due to day light savings time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create an SQL query:

```
select *
from tbl1
where date1 between @start and @end
```

This query always works until the daylight savings time changes in the UK.

After testing the query with sample data, it seems the query works fine which leads me to believe that the apps which are used to create the records in the table do not play well with daylight savings time. In other words, the days are wrong in daylight savings time when stored in the database.

I have spoken to the developers of the app and they do not seem interested in fixing their app, which puts me in a weird situation of having to make adjustments to my report to cater for bad data.

How can I make adjustments to the query above to cater for badly entered dates during day lights savings time in the database?

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server 2016 onwards, you can use AT TIMEZONE to apply specific DST based handlings.[Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/at-time-zone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
DECLARE @start DATETIME, @end DATETIME
SELECT @start =  CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), '2015-03-29T02:02:00', 126)     
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'; 
SELECT @end = CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), '2015-03-29T05:02:00', 126)     
AT TIME ZONE 'Central European Standard Time'; 

select *
from tbl1
where date1 between @start and @end
```